# How to upload an image to a model in Razor pages?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, web, razor-pages

I want to make an e-commerce like web app using ASP.NET Core.

Creating the models is ok, but I need to make a way to upload images for the products.

Razor pages allow only one `@model`, and this way I can't access the `Image` class that I created for uploading the images. This `Image` class is just a class for uploading, that will contain the path of the image, the id, the description and a `NotMapped` `IFormFile` property to do the upload.

But for UX purposes, the user(the owner of the e-commerce) to fill the `Product` model and uploading the image in the same page, and do the `POST` in the same form. But with the Razor pages allowing just one model, how can I do that? This way is dumb, impossible or both?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ithink i was not htinking straight enough. Just adding a property to my .cshtml.cs file appears to solve the problem. Will confirm later.

Comment: See here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/file-upload

Comment: @AlissonFabiano, I have given you an example below, if you have any other questions, please let me know.

Comment: @YongqingYu, thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But with the Razor pages allowing just one model, how can I do that?
> This way is dumb, impossible or both?

This is possible.

In `razor page`, we usually bind different models by adding different type `properties`, have a look for [this](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding).

According to your requirement, I created a demo for your reference:

Product model:

```
 public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
    }
```

Image model:

```
public class Image
{
    public string path { get; set; }
    public int id{ get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile file{ get; set; }
}
```

Page.cshtml.cs:

```
 public class UploadTestModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public Image  image { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public Product product { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
        public void OnPost()
        {

        }
    }
```

Page.cshtml:

```
@page
@model WebApplication_razorpage.Pages.UploadTestModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "UploadTest";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>UploadTest</h1>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ProductName:<input id="Text1" type="text" asp-for="product.Name" /><br />
    choose file:<input id="File1" type="file" asp-for="image.file" /><br />
    file description:<input id="Text1" type="text" asp-for="image.description" /><br />
    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

can I use multi file like that;

```
ProductName:<input id="Text1" type="text" asp-for="product.Name" /><br />
choose file1:<input id="File1" type="file" asp-for="image.file" /><br />
choose file1:<input id="File2" type="file" asp-for="image.file" /><br />
choose file1:<input id="File3" type="file" asp-for="image.file" /><br />
choose file1:<input id="File4" type="file" asp-for="image.file" /><br />
```